# If all liquid stuff inside the Earth turned solid, what would be the effect?

Tags: geomagnetism, earth-rotation, crust

There are parts inside the Earth (near the core) that are liquid. Presumably causing the Earth's magnetic field (though there are celestial bodies that are completely solid while they have a magnetic field around them).

In a comment to [another question](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/22354/can-changing-magnetic-fields-or-a-solidifying-core-cause-the-earth-to-rotate-fas), JeopardyTempest pointed out that solid iron and nickel (the main liquid stuff) has a density that is 15% higher than that of the liquid state. I can imagine that if this liquid stuff turns solid (though I'm not sure this will happen) this will affect the solid parts. But how?

Comment: If the liquid part turned solid, the missing magnetic field would be our least problem, because either Earth would have lost a lot of its mass, or the laws of physics would have been abolished.

Comment: speculative fictional what if's are not a great fit for this site,

Comment: This question is on topic here & depending on how it is considered it is not necessarily categorized as speculative fiction. Other planets/planetoids that once had a molten core, as Earth currently has, are now totally solid. The effect of this has been the shrinking of such planets resulting in large tectonic disruptions: faults, ridges, chasms, rifts etc. If I had the time to search for references concerning this  an answer would have been written. As to the magnetic field, it most likely would cease & atmospheric loses would most likely accelerate. Life on Earth would be totally different.